# Duplicate (repeat) rows in sql query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's say I have a table with two rows

```
 id | value |
----+-------+
 1  |   2   |
 2  |   3   |
```

I want to write a query that will duplicate (repeat) each row based on the value.
I want this result (5 rows total):

```
 id | value |
----+-------+
 1  |   2   |
 1  |   2   |
 2  |   3   |
 2  |   3   |
 2  |   3   |
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()`:

```
select t.id, t.value
from (select t.id, t.value, generate_series(1, t.value)
      from t 
     ) t;
```

You can do the same thing with a lateral join:

```
select t.id, t.value
from t, lateral
     generate_series(1, t.value);
```