# repeating / duplicating query entries based on a table value

Tags: sql, sybase, repeat, sqlanywhere

Related to / copied from this PostgreSQL topic: [so-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293084/duplicate-repeat-rows-in-sql-query-result)

> Let's say I have a table with two rows
>
> ```
>  id | value |
> ----+-------+
>  1  |   2   |
>  2  |   3   |
> ```
>
> I want to write a query that will duplicate (repeat) each row based on
>   the value.   I want this result (5 rows total):
>
> ```
>  id | value |
> ----+-------+
>  1  |   2   |
>  1  |   2   |
>  2  |   3   |
>  2  |   3   |
>  2  |   3   |
> ```

How is this possible in SQL Anywhere (Sybase SQL)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to have a numbers table . . . one that generates integers.  Perhaps you have one handy.  There are other ways.  For instance, using a recursive CTE:

```
with numbers as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from numbers
      where n < 100
)
select t.*
from yourtable t join
     numbers n
     on n.n <= value;
```

Not all versions of Sybase necessarily support recursive CTEs  There are other ways to generate such a table or you might already have one handy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it out as soon as I'm back at work tomorrow.