# Is there a way to repeat rows based on a counter column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have two tables A and B.

A has an id for rows in table B, and a counter:

```sql
b_id  integer not null references B(id),
count integer not null default 1
```

Is there a way in Postgres to return query of A with the rows in B where the rows are repeated `count` times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate (repeat) rows in sql query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293084/duplicate-repeat-rows-in-sql-query-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use `generate_series()`:

```
select t.*, n
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(1, t.count, 1) gs(n);
```

The above is actually the verbose way of writing the logic.  I prefer the above, because it is quite explicit about what is happening.  However, you can simplify this to:

```
select t.*, generate_series(1, t.count, 1) as n
from t;
```

Comment: So basically something like `select B.* from A join B on A.b_id=B.id, generate_series(1, A.count,1) n`

Comment: @Rob . . . I would never countenance the comma in the `from` clause.  Use an explicit `cross join`.  But that should work.